# AnkhSVN hangs in VisualStudio 2017 after changing SVN password

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2017, ankhsvn

I changed my password on SVN host (Assembla) and when using AnkhSVN in VisualStudio 2017 Community, Ankh asked for my new password, I entered it, but forgot to check the "Remember my password" checkbox. The password was correct as the svn actions worked.
But when I restarted VS2017 it froze.

I started VS2017 with the commandline `devenv /SafeMode` and that worked. I set the SourceControl plugin to none and closed VS2017.
I now starts without a problem, but when I select AnkhSVN as the SourceControl plugin, VS2017 hangs again.

I uninstalled and reinstalled AnkhSVN (2.9.58) again, but that didn't help either.

I suppose it is an authentication problem ? Can I force AnkhSVN to ask for my password again ?

I tried deleting de files in `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple` but that didn't help, VS2017 still hangs when selecting the AnkhSVN SourceControl plugin. So I guess it's not an authentication problem.

I also checked `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_122aad70\ActivityLog.xml` (by using `devenv /log`). The last entry is:

```
<entry>
  <record>615</record>
  <time>2021/05/26 22:05:43.906</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Begin package load [AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio]</description>
  <guid>{604AD610-5CF9-4BD5-8ACC-F49810E2EFD4}</guid>
</entry>
```

So, I guess it's a problem with the plugin, but why was there no problem before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I apparently missed there was an update for Visual Studio 2017, so I updated it to version 15.9.36.

When adding AnkhSVN (2.9.58) Visual Studio no longer hangs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different svn client (example: TortoiseSVN, or cmd-line) to set the password.
All SVN Clients share the same stored password mechanics.
You can also remove the stored password(s) by accessing the saved passwords which are available under `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple` removing the files inside will make SVN tools "forget" your passwords.

Comment: Thanks, I tried deleting the files, but VS2017 still hangs when selecting the plugin. I updated my question.